# Why the webrtc android camera stream is rotated at endpoint?

Tags: webrtc, android-camera, android-camera2, webrtc-android, janus-gateway

I am sending camera video from android to a janus server, but when I check from website, the video is rotated, Do you know why and How should I fix this?

[image: image demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change something in the room config
https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/issues/1021#issuecomment-335792000